# im having issues in clicking and filling an email label using selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)

driver.get("crm website ")

# Explicit wait for the "Compose" button to be clickable
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  
compose_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-test-id="compose-email-button"]'))) #this one works
compose_button.click()

# Explicit wait for the email input field to be present
email_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Select EmailRecipientSearchInput__StyledSelect-sc-13zzw9z-0 hSLceA private-form__selectplus private-form__selectplus--multi Select--multi is-searchable']")))#i get the error from here
email_input.click()
email_input.send_keys ("example@email.com")
```

after the compose button is clicked (its working ) i expect the script to click on email field and fill it , but i get this error
note : i trieeeed to change css selectors , xpaths ... did everything about the locators i gave up ,
this is the error message that im getting :
File "C:\Users\johnp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: